# How to connect to Apache in Gitlab-CI Runner context?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to connect to the Apache created in my `gitlab-ci.yml` (in order to run acceptance tests), but I don't understand how to do it.

Trying to `curl -i http://localhost/` gives:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

### Content of `gitlab-ci.yml`

```ruby
image: php:7.0-apache

variables:
 DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yqq
  - apt-get install -yqq curl net-tools

hello-world:
  stage: test
  script:
  - ./script.sh
```

### Content of `script.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

echo-run() {
    echo "===== ===== $1"
    echo "$($1)"
    echo
}

declare MYHOSTNAME="$(hostname)"

echo-run "hostname"
echo-run "netstat -antup"
echo-run "pwd"
echo-run "ls -al --color=auto ."
echo "curl -i http://${MYHOSTNAME}/"

# This does not work: "failed to connect to <hostname> port 80: Connection refused"
curl -i http://${MYHOSTNAME}/
```

The project is hosted at [gitlab.com/matt.faure/debug-ci/](https://gitlab.com/matt.faure/debug-ci) and here is the [ouput of a failed job](https://gitlab.com/matt.faure/debug-ci/-/jobs/104146889)

As far as I understand this an "inception" problem: in which world am I ?

`MYHOSTNAME` is the hostname of the Docker container, obviously this won't work as is it the name seen from *inside* the container, and IP/ports are mapped by the Runner (or maybe not). So what is the default mapping ? How to configure it ?

(This works in a regular Docker environment)

I harvested the [Gitlab Runner doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/README.html) without success. I also did extensive searches on Gitlab Forum and StackOverflow. I found these similar questions but none of them led me to a solution:

- [How are Gitlab CI service ports exposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496356/how-are-gitlab-ci-service-ports-exposed)
- Accepted answer to [GitLab runner unable to clone repository via http](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34007879/375376)
- [Gitlab runner: Not able to contact running webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904283/gitlab-runner-not-able-to-contact-running-webserver)

Summed up, what am I missing or misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Apache is just not running.

Your `netstat -antup` just shows *Foreign Addresses* connections, likely from apt-get ran before.

Gitlab Runner starts a container to execute your `before_script` `script` and `after_script`, it's overriding the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` that the image you're using rely on to start Apache normally.

Add a step in your script.sh to run apache in the background (not sure it will work though, I never tried), or just link apache as a [service](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#image-and-services), depending on your objective.

Comment: Thank you! I was facing a similar problem but with MySQL. Your answer led me to place the copy CMD from my Dockerfile into the before_script portion of my .gitlab-ci.yml and everything started working.